# cassandra-stress shows low read ops when node down (blocked on firewall)

Tags: cassandra

**cassandra version:** 3.11.13
**openjdk version** "1.8.0_342"
I did tests on small cluster 2 nodes, but also on a cluster with 6 nodes. Result is same.

I'm doing simple test

```
cassandra-stress read n=1000000 cl=LOCAL_ONE no-warmup -schema "replication(strategy=NetworkTopologyStrategy,dc1=2)" -mode native cql3  -rate threads=32  -node 192.168.1.131
```

**Test1**
shutdown one node

```
service cassandra stop
```

all looks fine - after short period of time `cassandra-stress` shows that `op/s` restored back.
No any problems, everything as I expected.

**Test2**
Instead of shutdown a process, I blocking network on one node, like this

```
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP && sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

then I see extremely low `op/s` in output exactly for 15 minutes, after this time `op/s` restored.

timing:
17:10 - blocked traffic on one node
17:25 - read ops restored themself
[image]

In a same time other nodes reporting that node is `DN` exactly after blocking on firewalls.
please help me to understand what happening.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me exactly what is unexpected in the scenario you described and what you need help with.

I suspect you're running a test on a very small cluster that probably only has 2 or 3 nodes. When you bring a node down, it is expected that the throughput will drop since you have reduced the capacity of the cluster.

If you need a bit more detail, then you will need to provide more information in your original question including details of your cluster configuration + steps on how to replicate your issue. Cheers!

Comment: Hello @erick-ramirez,
thank you for putting attention on my question. I edit my post. Hope now it's more clear.